# What fields are used by convertCurrency() function in SOQL when advanced currency management is enabled?

Tags: convertcurrency

The documentation for [convertCurrency()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_querying_currency_fields.htm) says this:

> “If an org has enabled advanced currency management, dated exchange rates are used when converting currency fields on opportunities, opportunity line items, and opportunity history. With advanced currency management, convertCurrency uses the conversion rate that corresponds to a given field (for example, CloseDate on opportunities).”

A "given field" of CloseDate is mentioned for Opportunity records, but I have not been able to find anything documented about how to find what field is used for an object.

CloseDate is mentioned in the example for Opportunity, but what about Opportunity Line Items? And other non-Opportunity-related objects?

And is CloseDate *always* the field used related to Opportunity?

Comment: This seems like a gap in the documentation. I checked the [Advanced Currency Management documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5) too and it seems vague as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc states that ACM is for Opportunity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm&type=5) (and related objects)

> Advanced currency management allows you to manage dated exchange rates within **opportunities** using Salesforce.

Hence `Opportunity.CloseDate` is the only relevant field for determining the currency rate to use.

You can't use ACM Dated Exchange rates on other objects as much as you might like to. See this [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpUrAAK) (and vote it up)